# Git: calculate code breakdown between two commits

Tags: git, statistics, diff

I have two commits, and I would like to calculate the code breakdown for them:

- NewLines: new lines of code
- RefactoredLines: lines of code that were modified/deleted and their last modification was more than 30 days ago
- ReworkedLines: lines of code that were modified/deleted and their last modification was less than 30 days ago

This is for the purpose of calculation this stats for any PR's to main/master branch

I know that there is `git diff <commitId> <commitId> --stat/numstat/shortstat`But it only shows insertion/deletion and does not have a context of the last known modification for a given line.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This isn't relevant to your question, but I'm chuckling at the comparison between the terms "refactored" and "reworked" in general, but also as defined by the previous modification time before the current change.

Comment: Can you elaborate? :)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a standard definition, but generally I think of "rework" as making some amount of changes, possibly including functional changes, or even a complete rewrite (but not necessarily). I think of "refactor" as a subset of that, where you re-organize the code and clean it up a bit, perhaps without changing functionality that much (but it still could). Perhaps you could make stricter definitions so that it's easier to categorize something as one or the other, and then land on: "refactor" is good and "rework" is bad. But, that is unrelated to the definitions you have...

Comment: cont... which is 2 changes to the same line of code within 30 days = rework, and 2 changes to the same line of code more than 30 days apart = refactor. IMHO, I don't think the time between changes is relevant at all for categorizing something as rework vs refactor, by any definition I can come up with. YMMV of course.

Comment: Again, I don't think this is relevant to your question because If you had called them "RecentLinesChanged" and "OlderLinesChanged" I wouldn't have commented. ;)